# Unable to select .Net 8.0 inside "functions worker" inside visual studio 17.8.6,, when creating azure funtions

Tags: azure

I have visual studio 2022 17.8.6, and .net 8.0 is installed as follow:-

[image]

but when i create a new azure function which run on timely bases to integrate with sharepoint, as follow:-

[image]

the .net 8.0 is not listed inside the "functions worker", as follow:-

[image]

any advice how i can create azure function using .net 8.0 ?? Thanks